# Unable to set the max date in the php

Tags: php

I want to set the max and min date in php..I can set the min date when max date has to be set to 2020-09-30 when in set max date it will show input type to dd-mm-2020.. Here is the code

```
<input type="date" name="mass_date" id="txtDate" required="required" class="col-md-12"  min="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 days")); ?>"  max='2020-09-30'  value="<?php if(isset($_GET['mass_date'])) { echo $_GET['mass_date']; } ?>" />
```

Comment: The input UI varies for each browsers. Or are you saying that if you remove `max` attribute, it will be displayed differently in a same browser?

Comment: You can not adjust the date format in input elements of the type date. The shown format depends on the internationalization settings of the used browser or the operating system. In german browsers the date will be shown in dd.mm.yyyy format. The browser support for this type of input element is weak and differs from browser to browser.